# Polar form of a complex measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, complex-numbers

Let $f:(X, \mathscr{A}) \to ( \mathbb{C}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{C}))$ be a measurable function. I need to show that there exists a measurable function $\theta: (X, \mathscr{A}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})) $ such that $f = e^{i \theta}|f|$. In the hints, the author suggests looking at $ \theta =2 \arctan  \left( \frac{\Im(f)}{\Re(f)+|f|} \right)$ on $\mathbb{C} - \mathbb{R}^{-}$.

Now my question is, can $\theta = \arctan \frac{ \Re(f)}{\Im(f)}$ work equally well?

Comment: It can't, $\frac{\Re f}{\Im f}$ doesn't distinguish between $f$ and $-f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, thank you. I forgot that in the trigonometric form of a complex number, $r$ can be positive or negative but here we have a positive number from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Daniel Fischer, the choice $\theta_f = \arctan \frac{ \Re(f)}{\Im(f)}$ cannot work since $\theta_f=\theta_{-f}$.